# What is the difference between "for(i=1;i<=10;i++)" and "for(i=1;i<=10;i++); ". How does the code work in both the cases?

Tags: c, for-loop, expression

When both the expressions were printed both gave a different output.
when the first program is executed i'm getting numbers from 1 to 10, when the second code is executed i'm getting only 11 as the output.
Why does this happen? How does putting a semicolon change the output of the code?

```
//program 1
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
  {
    printf("%d",i);
  }
} 

//program 2
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
 int i;
 for(i=1;i<=10;i++);
 {
   printf("%d",i);
 }
}
```

Comment: In the second example `printf("%d",i);` will only happen *once* because it isn't in the loop – it is in another code block.

Comment: `for(i=1;i<=10;i++);` is the same as `for(i=1;i<=10;i++) { /* Empty */ }`

Comment: Looks like a test for the eyes.

Comment: a `;` I would say

Comment: C has the concept of an "empty statement", which is just the semicolon. It does nothing, 10 times. Then it prints i, 1 time :-).

Comment: Compiled with sufficient high warning level (e.g. gcc -Wall -Wextra ....) you will get warnings for the second example. Those warnings clearly explains the problem: `this 'for' clause does not guard...  ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the 'for'`

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon signifies the end of an operation. So, when you have

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++);
```

basically you say that let's loop with the help of `i` that's initially 1 and finally 10, stepping 1 each time, without doing anything else. When you say:

```
for(i=1;i<=10;i++) { /* ... */ }
```

basically you say that let's loop with the help of `i` that's initially 1 and finally 10, stepping 1 each time, executing the code (whatever it is) inside the block. So, your

```
 for(i=1;i<=10;i++);
 {
   printf("%d",i);
 }
```

loops with the help of `i` that changes from 1 to 10, being incremented upon each step and do nothing in any of the steps. After the loop ends, `printf` will be executed and prints 11, because `i` increased 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 during the loop, until the criteria of `i <= 10` became false, `i` becoming 11 and by the time your code arriving to execute the code after your loop, it prints `i`, which is 11 by that time. By contrast:

```
 for(i=1;i<=10;i++)
 {
   printf("%d",i);
 }
```

is a loop where `i` will get the values of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 and execute the `printf` for each of them. Then, `i` as usual is incremented, becoming 11, so the loop criteria is no longer true and the loop will no longer execute the code block attached to it.